# i have got state after rerender! but i want state after dispatch which is inside useEffect something like get data onloading how is it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have got state after rerender! but i want state after dispatch which is inside useEffect something like get data onloading how is it?

```
const [que, setQue] = useState('');

const ques = useSelector(state => state.getQuestions.data);

useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(GetQuestion({ org_id: 3 }))
    setQue(ques)
    console.log("fetch: ", ques)
    console.log("que: ", que)
    setLoading(false)
}, [dispatch])
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need another useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GetQuestion({ org_id: 3 }))
    setQue(ques)
    console.log("fetch: ", ques)
    console.log("que: ", que)
    setLoading(false)
}, [])
```

Which will execute onLoad (but be careful, it will also execute every time it this components re-renders)

Comment: When you put **dispatch** as the second parameter of the useEffect it will trigger that function everytime your dispatch changes,

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are dispatching on each render, which will cause another re-render. What you can simply do is check the que (queue?) and then either dispatch if empty, or set if your selector correctly returns.

```
const [que, setQue] = useState(false);

const ques = useSelector(state => state.getQuestions.data);

useEffect(() => {
    if(!que && ques) {
       setQue(ques)
       console.log("fetch: ", ques)
       console.log("que: ", que)
       setLoading(false)
    } else if(!que && !ques) {
       dispatch(GetQuestion({ org_id: 3 }))
    }
}, [dispatch, ques])
```

Comment: @Azharuddinmulla - can you create a sandbox for us to try and help?

Comment: please provide me github account i will send you code.